# Android ListView ScrollTo, scrolls to top after touch

Tags: android, android-listview, touch-event, android-scroll

I'm programmatically setting scrolled Y coordinate of my ListView to 720pixels.
It works fine, but when the user touches the ListView it jumps back to top. No scroll, but I can see the content change and it's at the top of the list.
The ListView contains only one item representing hours in a day from 0:00 to 23:00 which I inflate using a custom adapter.

I've tried overriding onScrollChanged, onTouch etc. Nothing works.

The ListView is inflated in the ViewPager's adapter.
And it's in there I set the scrollTo property.

Is there any way to stop the ListView from going to the top?

Answer (score -1):

Fixed it by using ScrollView instead of ListView as ListView only had 1 item.